# XSLT - Transform XML to a different XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I Need to create an XSL file so that I will use it to transform one XML to another XML.
The problem is, I dont really know XPath nor XSLT.
So my question is, is there some tool that can help me with that or do I need to sit back and start reading about XPath & XSLT?

Thanks,

Comment: "Do I need to learn `(language|tool)` in order to use it?" is not a real question. Please rephrase it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to sit back and start reading about XPath and XSLT.

I find the tutorials on [zvon](http://zvon.org/) to be quite good.

This [page](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) is quite good for playing around with XPath and XSLT and trying things out.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589) for more tutorials and books about XSLT.

Comment: +1. Michael Kay is known to be a guru in this area, try his books as well: http://www.amazon.com/XSLT-XPath-Programmers-Reference-Programmer/dp/0470192747/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1295944229&sr=1-2

Comment: @Yan - yes, he is. His books are listed on the answer I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I find [Altova MapForce](http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html) particulary useful for this task